# What's the use case for Functional interface other than different implementations using Lambda expressions?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I am wondering what would be a use case for functional interface other than different implementations using lambda expressions?

Here is the basic example for functional interface:

```
/*Basic example for Functional interface with Lambda expression*/

public class Lambda_test {

    /*
     * Functional Interface annotation will not allow to declare more than one
     * abstract method which is obvious for the concept
     */

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface NameTest {

        // One abstract method
        abstract String MyName(String name);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NameTest nametest = (name) -> "Ashwin " + name + "!";

        System.out.println("My name is " + nametest.MyName("Savaj"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to java specification https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract method
>   (aside from the methods of Object), and thus represents a single
>   function contract.

Since default methods have an implementation, they are not abstract.

In case of @FunctionalInterface :
A compiler will produce an error message unless:

1. The type is an interface type and not an annotation type, enum, or
   class.
2. The annotated type satisfies the requirements of a functional
   interface.